# Cython pyx modification for multidimensional numpy input with memory views

Tags: python, numpy, cython, memoryview

My current input of a function wrapped from a c++ class is a one dimensional numpy array, e.g., func(np.array([1,2,3])) for which my cython description in the pyx looks like the following:

```
def func(self, double[::1]  arr):
        return self.c_obj.update_set_point(&arr[0])
```

However, I am rather confused how I should change it if my input array looks like  np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

Can anyone describe in general how the pyx description should vary for multidimensional array input with the above 2 dimensional array as an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your arrays are two-dim, then the memoryview syntax is `double[:, ::1]` etc.

If you want to take a memoryview on an array with the number of dimensions only known at runtime, then you're out of luck. Probably the only way is to save the shape, flatten, process the flattened array, and restore the shape on return.

Comment: how about if it is 3 or 4 dimensional?

Comment: Same: flatten, loop over, restore the shape.